# Javascript - check if string is valid CSS number

Tags: javascript, css, numbers

I need RegExp or something alike to detect if string is of [CSS number data type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/number).

It must NOT use an external library or a Web API. Just plain javascript.

Examples of valid CSS numbers:

```
12
00012
-12
+12
4.01
-456.8
1.200000
.0
0.0
+0.0
-0.0
-1.2
-.2
+.2
.60
10e3
1.2e2
-1.2e2
.2e2
21.2E5
1.2e+2
-3.4e-2
```

Invalid numbers:

```
e2
1e
20.
20.e3
1.2.
+-12.2
0x11
0b11
0o11
-.
+.
.
```

Comment: Please add your attempt and describe what problems you have with it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is this:

```
function isCssNumber(string) {
    return /^[-+]?\d*\.?\d+([eE]?[-+]?\d+)?$/.test(string)
}
```